# Get frame of the root view without the safe area edges programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to add a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to the main view.
I settled by setting the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer frame  to the view frame and then adding it as its sublayer. The problem is that the previewLayer is not fully sized to the phone screen but it displays In the safe area of the phone. Does anybody know how to get the view frame without the upper and bottom safe edges?
Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this in viewDidLoad:

```
yourView.bounds = self.view.bounds
```